# Using l10n (language localized) strings with ARIA

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, wai-aria

I'm trying to make my extension to use the aria tags through localized strings, as explained in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/l10n). So, I have a properties file with things like:

```
new_file=New file
new_file.ariaLabel=Creates a new file
```

And then, I'm trying to use it inside my sidebar html code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn ui-button">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" 
        data-l10n-id="new_file" 
        aria-label="new_file.ariaValueText"/>
</button>
```

The new_file works in the span, I can read it, but not the aria label. I tryed without specifying an aria-label in the html, also to write anything, and it doesn't work. What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your sidebar an xhtml file. Then use l10n xhtml localization: https://github.com/Noitidart/l10n/tree/xhtml-xul you can use this technique to populate your `aria-` tags.

Here's a great guide on MDN for exactly the github link i gave you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions#Localization_%28L10n%29

Here's a link to l10n html options page (xhtml is just html with localization files) https://github.com/Noitidart/l10n/tree/html-options